# What is mean by Metafunctions & Metaclasses in Programming Languages?

Tags: templates, compiler-construction, c++14, programming-languages, metaprogramming

I have come across these terms many times during compile time c++ computation. I have searched through the web, the resources I found where "expert level" stuffs I can't able to understand it. Could please help to understand these terms ? I'm looking for beginner-level good explanation. 
Thanks a lot for your kind help!
Pree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Metafunctions

A metafunction in C++ is a way of expressing a compile-time computation using template metaprogramming -- using template instantiation and type deduction to generate results at compile time.

Fundamentally, a metafunction is a class template with `constexpr` members (for metafunctions returning values) or typedefs (for metafunctions returning types). 
The technique can be illustrated by the metafunction `is_same` which checks if two type parameters are the same. A possible implementation (from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)) is

```
template<class T, class U>
struct is_same : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_same<T, T> : std::true_type {};
```

where `std::true_type` is a helper metafunction that has a member `constexpr bool value = true` (and `false` for `false_type`).

A metafunction is called by instantiating the template and reading the member containing the result, for instance the expression

```
is_same<int,int32_t>::value
```

which will evaluate to the boolean value `true` if `int` is 32 bits, and `false` otherwise.

Another example, from `type_traits` is `std::is_floating_point`, which checks if a type is a floating point type. It can be called as

```
is_floating_point<int>::value
```

The standard library (mostly) has the convention that metafunctions returning values have the member `value`, and metafunctions returning types have the type alias `type`.

An example of a type-returning metafunction is `std::iterator_traits` which is used to get information about iterators. For intance, given an iterator type `Iter`, one can get the value type (i.e., the type returned by dereferencing the iterator) with

```
iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type
```

and the iterator category (e.i., `ForwardIterator`, `RandomAccessIterator`, etc.) with

```
iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category
```

An example of compile-time computation is a metafunction that computes the factorial:

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct Fac{
    static constexpr unsigned int value = N * Fac<N-1>::value; 
};

template <>
struct Fac<0>{
    static constexpr unsigned int value = 1;
};
```

Again, this metafunction is called as `Fac<5>::value`

### Metaclasses

Metaclasses is a proposed addition to C++ to allow expressing constraints on a (kind of) class in code instead of just using conventions and documentation.

For instance, an "interface" is often used to describe a class that has

1. only pure virtual public function
2. a virtual destructor

With a metaclass `interface`, that could be written

```
interface Example {
    void Foo();
    int  Bar(int);
}
```

which would then be instantiated by the compiler to the class

```
 class Example {
 public:
     virtual void Foo() =0;
     virtual int Bar(int) =0;
     virtual ~Foo() =default;
 }
```

A good summary of the metaclass proposal can be found at this [fluentc++](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/08/04/metaclasses-cpp-summary/) blog post. A comprehensive source is [Herb Sutter's blog post](https://herbsutter.com/2017/07/26/metaclasses-thoughts-on-generative-c/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice explanation !